# What is the actual meaning of priority/confidence in findbugs ?

Tags: findbugs

When I use fingbugs-eclipse plugin or findbugs-ant plugin, there is a confidence option to be set.

[image]

But according to findbugs document, bugs are given a rank 1-20, and grouped into the categories scariest (rank 1-4), scary (rank 5-9), troubling (rank 10-14), and of concern (rank 15-20). So what is the actual meaning of priority/confidence ?  Does it have a relationship for Bug Rank? If so, how to understand?  It not, why does findbug define a confidence for every bug ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A rule's `confidence` measures the likelihood that it has flagged a real bug. Simple rules that use evidence from a single instruction or two or that detect a well-known source of bugs are more likely to find a real bug than those using inference, inspecting instructions from multiple methods, or flagging code that in many cases is perfectly reasonable.

Prior to [version 2](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/findbugs2.html) `confidence` was known as `priority`, but this caused confusion due to most developers' understanding of the word `priority`:

> [M]any people were confused by the priority reported by FindBugs, and considered all HIGH priority issues to be important. To reflect the actually [sic] meaning of this attribute of issues, it has been renamed confidence. Issues of different bug patterns should be compared by there rank, not their confidence.

A rule's `rank` measures the severity of the problem. It varies from 20 (lowest) to 1 (highest), and the UI groups the values into four categories: `scariest`, `scary`, `troubling`, and `of concern`.

For example, worn break pads might receive a `rank` of 10 while a cut break line would get 1. Your mechanic might report high `confidence` that your break line is cut by simple inspection but low `confidence` that the knocking he hears in your engine indicates a damaged piston.